# Inspect all elements in Numpy array (and Pandas DataFrame) and change selectively

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that we have a numpy 2d array (or a Pandas DataFrame) with variable lengths in both rows and columns.

Is there a quick way to inspect all elements and clip to the pre-specified max value (if any element is larger than the pre-specified max value) in either numpy ndarray or pandas DataFrame, whichever is simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` - use [`DataFrame.clip_upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html):

```
np.random.seed(2018)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)))

print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  2  9  5  4
1  6  9  9  7  9
2  6  6  1  0  6
3  5  6  7  0  7
4  8  7  9  4  8

print (df.clip_upper(5))
   0  1  2  3  4
0  5  2  5  5  4
1  5  5  5  5  5
2  5  5  1  0  5
3  5  5  5  0  5
4  5  5  5  4  5
```

`Numpy` - use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
np.random.seed(2018)
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5))
print (arr)
[[6 2 9 5 4]
 [6 9 9 7 9]
 [6 6 1 0 6]
 [5 6 7 0 7]
 [8 7 9 4 8]]

print (np.clip(arr, arr.min(), 5))
[[5 2 5 5 4]
 [5 5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 1 0 5]
 [5 5 5 0 5]
 [5 5 5 4 5]]
```

Comment: @east - Glad can help!